# How can $F^{\infty}$ be defined over a field F?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-fields

Since, an $n$ - $tuple$ is only defined when its length i.e $n$ is non-negative and finite.

If an element of $F^{\infty}$ is of the form $(x_1,x_2,x_3,.....)$, then how can it be a defined vector space?

I know that $F^{\infty}$ satisfies the properties concerning the usual operations of vector addition and scalar multiplication.

But my doubt arised from the definition of a **list** of **length** $n$ (or an $n$ - $tuple$) as mentioned in **Linear Algebra Done Right - Sheldon Axler**.

I have attached the screenshots from the book to verify my doubt.

Definitions as mentioned in the book:
[**List of length $n$**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWqnc.jpg)  ,
[$F^{n}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rbd4.jpg)  ,  [$F^{\infty}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9D7W.jpg)

Comment: You can define it as $F^{\mathbb{N}}$, or in other words, the set of functions $\mathbb{N}\to F$. The operation of addition is addition of function $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and multiplication by an element $\alpha\in F$ by $(\alpha f)(x)=\alpha f(x)$.

Comment: A vector space doesn't _have_ to be finite-dimensional; many things other than the 'list of length n' can be vector spaces over a given field.  $F^\infty$ is one good example of that. Another is $F^\omega$, the set of all _finite_ (but arbitrary) length sequences of $F$, with the usual operations. These are both vector spaces over $F$, neither is finite-dimensional, but they (generally) have different cardinalities. These can be identified with the vector spaces of polynomials, $F^\omega\equiv F[t]$, and of formal power series, $F^\infty\equiv F[[t]]$.

Comment: Thanks @StevenStadnicki. I didn't think of the abstractness of the concept as you described. It seems too trivial now.